# When can I call multiprocess.close() or process.join() after early return in flask function?

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

what i wanted to do
When the flask application receives a request to  to a specific endpoint (eg /scale-up),
Since it takes more than 5 minutes to turn on the EC2 instance, I try to run that logic in a different process and send a response directly(don't wait until that process turn on EC2 instance) to the user who sent the request.

**But when this happens, I don't know when I can close() and join() the process.**

**To recap,
When a request comes in, it only 'executes' a process that takes a long time, and apart from that I just send a OK response. After that, how can I close and join this process?**

I tried to use flask's teardown_request decorator, but this also doesn't seem to be the right way.

Here is my code.

```
import multiprocessing
from flask import Flask, Response
from multiprocessing import Pool

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route(f'/scale-up')
def send_scale_up_request():
    try:
        p = Pool(4)

        p.apply_async(scale_up_instance)

        logger.info("Executing to restart the instance...")
        return Response("Executing to restart the instance...")
        # where can I put p.close() and p.join()??

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error occured")
        logger.error(e)
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc(limit=None))

def scale_up_instance():
    # turn on EC2 instance using aws sdk(boto3)
    .....
```

Thank you very much. This is my first time asking a question here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to be using a multiprocessing pool to be running a single process and so there is also no need for `close` and `join`. But even running a single `Process`, there is really no place or need to put a call to `join` for it. The process will run asynchronously and end after your current request has terminated.

**Update**

To prevent *defunct* processes because you cannot do a `join` on the started process, instead run `scale_up_instance` as a thread. If for some reason threading is not sufficient, the thread can start a process that can be joined:

```py
import multiprocessing
from flask import Flask, Response
from threading import Thread
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route(f'/scale-up')
def send_scale_up_request():
    try:
        Thread(target=scale_up_instance).start()

        logger.info("Executing to restart the instance...")
        return Response("Executing to restart the instance...")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error occured")
        logger.error(e)
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc(limit=None))

def scale_up_instance():
    # turn on EC2 instance using aws sdk(boto3)
    import time
    print('starting...')
    time.sleep(10)
    print('ending.')
    # If multiprocessing is required because of GIL restrictions then:
    from multiprocessing import Process
    p = Process(target=do_scale_up) # defined elsewhere
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.   

I also thought that code you gave as an example. But the reason I suddenly thought that I should use pool, close, and join is, 
1. If a lot of '/scale-up' requests come at the same time, wouldn't there be any problems?   
2. And if you don't use join(), doesn't it become "the child process will sit idle and not terminate, becoming a zombie you must manually kill"?   


Sorry if my question is immature.    
Thank you.

Comment: If another **/scale-up** request came in you would be creating a new pool of 4 processes and what is the point of that? `join` is not for the purposes of terminating a process *per se*; it is for the purposes of blocking until the subprocess ends. Even without the join the process will run and complete processing on its own. Yes, it's true that if you display tasks with, for example, **ps -ef**, it will show up as a defunct process (at least on my Debian Linux). But I don't see how you can save the `Process` instance to later join it because it can't be saved, for instance, in the `session`.

Comment: I will have a solution for you! See update.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and examples. 
Just one more question, How about using Celery and running it asynchronously in the background?
What is a better way b/w multiprocessing or using celery in production env?

Thank you.